# Erro em "switch case"

Tags: java, switch

Estou com um erro em um dos `case`s do `switch`, o erro é esse:

[image: Erro mostrado]

Estou fazendo um CRUD de uma biblioteca, quando vocês virem o código, talvez achem estranho uma coisa:

Eu fiz alguns `switch` com apenas 1 opção, pois cada opção leva pra um menu diferente

```
@Override
public int Menu(int menu) {
    int opc=0;

    System.out.println("-======MENU======-\n\n" +
            "1. Cadastrar\n" +
            "2. Editar\n" +
            "3. Pesquisar\n" +
            "4. Listar\n" +
            "5. Excluir\n" +
            "6. Excluir tudo\n" +
            "7. Sair");
    return opc;
}
```

A primeira opção vai pro menu de cadastrar, a segunda vai para o menu de editar... então achei melhor fazer um `switch` com uma opção pra cada menu.

Vou disponibilizar o código pra vocês no meu GitHub, pois é muito extenso pra colocar aqui, o erro está na classe Principal, mais especificamente na linha 198, onde tem escrito:

**O erro acontece exatamente aqui:**

```
case  2 : {         
    Biblioteca.MenuEditar(opc);
}
```

[Meu Github](https://github.com/ViniciusStark/Codes).

Comment: Tem como por só a assinatura do método `Biblioteca.MenuEditar`? Parece que você espera um booleano na assinatura, porém está passando um inteiro

Comment: Juro que tentei ler seu código, mas ele não está belo, o que acaba que influi na legibilidade. Creio que, para cada caso do `switch`, seria melhor delegar para uma função/método que trata do desejado. Por exemplo, o caso 1 chama a função de cadastros, que essa por sua vez teria um `switch` jogando para métodos de `cadastrarAutor` (caso 1), `cadastrarEditora` (caso 2) etc

Comment: public int menuEditar(int menu);

Comment: Tenta compilar com `javac` e nos mostra os erros que o compilador solta, talvez tenhamos mais dicas

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque seu switch acaba antes do `case 2:`, na linha 188.

Como [disse o Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216376/erro-em-switch-case#comment442401_216376), seu código está pouco legível, tanto pela formatação quanto pelo excesso de sentenças em cada case, e isso faz com que seja difícil identificar onde acaba e onde começa cada bloco.

Seguindo a sugestão dele, modularize seu código, colocando os blocos dos cases em funções para simplificar os switchs, por exemplo:

```
    // primeiro switch: opc = biblioteca.menu()
    switch(opc) {
        case 1: cadastrar(); break;
        case 2: editar(); break;
        case 3: pesquisar(); break;
        case 4: listar(); break;
        case 5: excluir(); break;
        case 6: excluirTudo();
        case 7: sair(); break;
        default: break;
    }

    // segundo switch: opc = biblioteca.menuCadastrar()
    switch(opc) {
        case 1: cadastrarAutor(); break;
        case 2: cadastrarEditora(); break;
        case 3: cadastrarLivro(); break;
        case 4: voltar(); break;
        case 5: sair(); break;
        default: break;
    }
```

Você poderia também, por exemplo, ter classes pra cada caso do primeiro menu: uma classe especializada em cadastrar, outra especializada em editar, outra em listar, etc, que saberiam chamar os métodos corretos da classe Biblioteca.

Comment: Eu acho que isso é mais digno de um _pull request_ do que de resposta

Answer (score -1):

Está faltando o break;
Existe uma parte do seu case no github que falta o break.
aqui vai um exemplo :

```
int diaDaSemana = 1;
    switch (diaDaSemana) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Domingo");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Segunda-feira");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Terça-feira");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Quarta-feira");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Quinta-feira");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Sexta-feira");
            break;
         case 7:
            System.out.println("Sábado");
            break;
        default:
             System.out.println("Este não é um dia válido!");
     }
```

Comment: A ausência de `break` não gera erro de sintaxe. Quando se deseja cascatear o efeito de um caso para o seguinte, basta omitir o `break` (mas normalmente não é isso o desejado)

Answer (score -1):

O erro ocorre pois esta faltando o break nesta parte do **código:**

```
case 2:{        
     biblioteca.menuEditar(opc);
     break;     
}
```

Comment: A ausência de `break` não gera erro de sintaxe. Quando se deseja cascatear o efeito de um caso para o seguinte, basta omitir o `break` (mas normalmente não é isso o desejado)